# how I use skinny tables in a sandbox

Tags: sandbox, ldv, skinny-table

If I plan to use Skinny tables in my org, and say use it for accounts to improve performance issues, and as a result, set up say 30 fields in the skinny table, how do this work in the sandbox if skinny tables are not copied to a sandbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented in [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_skinny_tables.htm) that

> For Full sandboxes: Skinny tables are copied to your Full sandbox orgs.

> For other types of sandboxes: Skinny tables aren’t copied to your sandbox organizations. To have production skinny tables activated for sandbox types other than Full sandboxes, contact Salesforce Customer Support.

The place you're most likely to need skinny tables for performance *is* in a Full Copy due to the data volume you can achieve in that environment.

Comment: thanks David, I'm puzzled at how one can develop in let's say a developer s/boox and then promote code etc. to higher env't that has uses skinny table, do all the fields in skinny table exist already in the main table but just get referenced?so in essence code or developers never have to ref to the skinny table

Comment: @Bart You (as a developer) do not have access to the skinny table. This is created at the database level by the platform and when access to fields on such skinny tables is needed from your running SOQL, the platforms job is to retrieve from the correct table i.e Object Standard Table and Object Skinny Table.